# Anyone experienced in real-time Java on embedded systems?

Tags: java, real-time

Has anyone out there implemented a real-time embedded Java system?  I am very interested to see if this could work for a new product I'm developing, but am unsure of how the whole real-time responsiveness & garbage collection work.  Would really like to contact anyone who's done a real-time Java system before.

Comment: You are aware that "real time" refers to that "things are guaranteed to happen before X cycles" where X can be large, and not "things happen very fast"?

Comment: Yes, looking to see if hard real time can be done with Java.

Comment: I'd tread with caution.  Thinks like gc, JIT-compiling at run time can cause unpredictable delays.  Java doesn't seem like a good choice for this sort of thing

Comment: Please contact me if you have any RT/embedded Java questions.  I can help out.  But on StackOverflow, you need to ask specific questions with well-defined answers... likely to get closed...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Java Optimized Processor](http://www.jopdesign.com/). It's the implementation of JVM in the hardware. This system can be used as a real-time embedded system.